# Attaching a current User object to Django form

Tags: python, django, forms

I am working on an app that has a section with with a file upload form for .txt fiels.  I would like for the current user that is uploading the file to be added along with the file and the file name.  Currently, I can do this successfully in the admin section but I just cant get it to save via the form itself.  Any Ideas?

Here are the models:

```
class UploadedTextFile(models.Model):
file = models.FileField(upload_to="textfiles")
filename = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
username = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)


class UploadedTextFileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadedTextFile
        fields = ['file', 'filename']
```

Here is my view:

```
def inputtest(request):

#response for file being submited
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UploadedTextFileForm(request.POST)  
        if form.is_valid():
            new_form = form.save(commit=False)
            new_form.username = request.user
            new_form.save()


        return render(request, 'about.html')

    inputtest = UploadedTextFileForm()
    return render(request, 'failed.html', {'inputtest': inputtest})

    else:
        inputtest = UploadedTextFileForm()
        return render(request, 'inputtest.html', {'inputtest': inputtest})
```

Here is my html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ inputtest.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it in the view (as you've shown) is the right way to do this. Most likely you're having problems because you've left `username` as a field on the form, and because the FK model field doesn't have `blank=True` set the form requires the field to be provided. You should explicitly declare just the subset fields that you want to accept user input for in the form's `Meta` class.

```
class UploadedTextFileForm(ModelForm):                
    class Meta:                                       
        model = UploadedTextFile
        fields = ['file', 'filename']
```

I am not sure why you're rendering a different template when the form is not valid, but no matter what you're not providing the form object in the context. This means that you'll never see any errors the form detects, which is probably what's happening with this code - you're not seeing the error that `username` is not provided.

Comment: Hi Peter.  I made all the changes you suggested. Unfortunately it's still not working.  By rearranging render statements I have narrowed it down to the fact that the form is not validating.  I edited my question to represent said changes.  Any clue whats going on?

Comment: And I officially have a potato for a brain.  I followed peters advice, and my form would still not validate.  This was because I was leaving out enctype="multipart/form-data".  Everything works now.  You are the BEST stackoverflow.