# Django Model Form not saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a Django model form which when I use the following, isn't saving

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AbsenceForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class AbsenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NotWorking
        exclude = ['user']
        widgets = {
            'date': DateInput()
        }
```

Can you help please.

Comment: Do `print form.errors` when is not valid.

Comment: It is valid and it is not saving

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `instance` wrong.

`instance` on a model form is supposed to be of the same class as the model you're referring to. It is used in `UpdateView`s to bind the form to an existing instance instead of creating a new instance up on `save`.

Example from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method):

```
# Create a form to edit an existing Article, but use
# POST data to populate the form.
>>> a = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> f = ArticleForm(request.POST, instance=a)
>>> f.save()
```

In order to attach the user instance to the form you should set it on the form instead of providing it as an `instance` argument like detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799941/attaching-a-current-user-object-to-django-form).

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AbsenceForm(request.POST)
    form
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
```